# Foreach Loop in EmbPerl

Tags: perl, embperl

Seems like variables declared outside foreach, initialized inside foreach will not persist its data.

Consider this example :

```
[-
$myVar;

foreach my $item (qw/item1 item2 item3/) {
    $myVar = $item;
}

print $myVar # This will print undef, I expect it to print item3
-]
```

How do I make this work with foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `print $myVar` sentence to `print OUT $myVar;`
OUT filehandle is tied to Embperl's output stream. You can use also a `[+ $myVar +]` block instead of printing to OUT.